# Convert HTML content to Pdf using c# and asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, pdf

Here iam trying to convert the content inside **html div tag to pdf** i found the following error:

`Input string was not in a correct format is occur`

Here is the code i tried using c#:

```
    divexcel.Visible = true;
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    divexcel.RenderControl(hw);
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 80f, 80f, -2f, 35f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    //head.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, page.Width / 8, page.Height - pdfDoc.TopMargin + head.TotalHeight, writer.DirectContent);
    //pdfDoc.Add(headerTbl);   
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();
------------------------------------------
```

Here is my html code

```
<div id="divexcel" runat="server">
    <table id="tbDetails" width="800px">
    <thead >
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Which line gives you this error?

Comment: htmlparser.Parse(sr);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace width="800px" on width="800". Should work